# Attract data-rel and display the value

Tags: jquery, html, append

I have added a "Hint" option for a "puzzle" I am creating but I could only manage to create an alert to display the `data-rel` value that actually represents the correct position of the clicked piece.

What I hope of achieving is when you double click on the puzzle piece to display the `data-rel` over the piece, `position "absolute" on top-left` corner and to stay there, like so:

[image: How it should turn out]

I believe I should appendTo the data-rel over the .puzzle div but I'm a bit confused on how to do that.
Here is what I managed to pull off so far:

**HTML**

```
<div id="shell">
    <div class="puzzle" data-rel="10"></div>
    <div class="puzzle" data-rel="1"></div>
    <div class="puzzle" data-rel="4"></div>
    <div class="puzzle" data-rel="7"></div>
    <div class="puzzle" data-rel="11"></div>
    <div class="puzzle" data-rel="2"></div>
    <div class="puzzle" data-rel="5"></div>
    <div class="puzzle" data-rel="8"></div>
    <div class="puzzle" data-rel="12"></div>
    <div class="puzzle" data-rel="6"></div>
    <div class="puzzle" data-rel="9"></div>
    <div class="puzzle" data-rel="3"></div>
</div>
<div id="final"></div>
<div class="skip">*I'm not in the mood, just show me...</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#final').hide();

    var key = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
    $('#shell').sortable({
        cursor: 'move',
        update: function (event, ui) {
            var numbers = $('.puzzle[data-rel]').map(function () {
                return parseInt($(this).attr('data-rel'));
            });
            console.log(numbers);
            if (key.equals(numbers)) {
                $('.skip').delay(500).fadeOut(1000);
                $('#shell').animate({opacity:0.1});
                $('#shell').animate({opacity:1});
                $('#shell').delay(500).fadeOut(1000);
                $('#final').delay(2500).fadeIn(2000);
            }
        }
    });
});

Array.prototype.equals = function (array) {
    if (!array) return false;
    if (this.length != array.length) return false;
    for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (this[i] instanceof Array && array[i] instanceof Array) {
            if (!this[i].equals(array[i])) return false;
        } else if (this[i] != array[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};

$('.skip').click(function() {
                $('.skip').delay(500).fadeOut(1000);
                $('#shell').delay(500).fadeOut(1000);
                $('#final').delay(1500).fadeIn(2000);
});

$('.puzzle').bind('dblclick',function(){
  var hint = $(this).attr('data-rel');
    alert('Position: '+ hint);
})
```

And for better understanding and CSS, here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/uxmFN/9/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$('.puzzle').bind('dblclick',function(){
  var hint = $(this).attr('data-rel');
  $(this).append('<span class="hint" style="display: none;">'+hint+'</span>');
  $(this).children('.hint').show(500);
});
```

Make sure your .puzzle has:

```
position: relative;
```

And your .hint has something like (and font styling):

```
position: absolute; top: 2px; left: 2px; z-index: 2;
```

You may also want to remove the hint when they move a piece again by using:

```
$('.hint').hide(500, function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: With a little styling that worked out great, thanks a lot for the help :D Have a nice day !!!

Comment: Also, instead of '.html' i had to use '.append' because .html removed my image between the '.puzzle' classed div and would replace it with the hint classed span :D

Comment: Ahh, I didn't see that in the jQuery, just saw the empty divs in the html sample. Updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: No problem, it kinda is my fault cause I didn't place it but I didn't find it relevant :D anyway, thanks :)